# ¿Puedo declarar una función con def dentro de un if en Python?

Tags: python

¿Se puede poner un `def` dentro de un `if`?.

Ejemplo

```
eligio = raw_input("""
1)otro
2)otro
3)otro
Selecciona :><: """)

if eligio =="1":
    def html(link):
```

Claramente después de ese `def` le sigue más código, pero al momento de ponerlo debajo de ese `if`, el código no actúa.

Antes de hacer esta pregunta revise en google sobre esto y nada, vi si era el código el que estaba mal o mal indentado y nada.

Sólo quiero saber eso, o si hay alguna otra manera de hacer actuar el script que contiene el `def`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludo!

Aunque sintacticamente no este bien visto que una funcion se declare e inicialice dentro de un *if*, en *Python* **Si es posible** hacerlo:

He aqui tu codigo:

```
eligio = raw_input("""
1) Opcion 1
2) Opcion 2
3) Opcion 3
Selecciona :><: """)

if eligio =="1":
    def html(link):
        print "Hola mundo"

    html(1)  # Realizamos el llamado a la funcion para que ejecute
```

*Resultado:*

```
 1) Opcion 1                                                                                                                                                          
 2) Opcion 2                                                                                                                                                          
 3) Opcion 3                                                                                                                                                          
 Selecciona :><: 1                                                                                                                                                    
Hola mundo
```

**Nota:** Obviamente, debes llamar a tu funcion, para que esta se ejecute, sino, esta no correra

Comment: Gracias, cuando realizo el llamado el script que incruste ahi se ejecute mal (con un except que tenia puesto por si hay un error) y cuando ejecuto el 2 o 3, me da un error de que html no esta definido

Comment: @Snoop13 el ejemplo de Ivan es correcto, si te da error podrias aportar más información para poder ayudarte. En cuanto a si eliges 2 o 3, logicamente la función `html` **solo existe si se entra en el condicional**, si se elige 2 o 3 no se entra en el `if`, no se ejecuta ese código por lo que la función no está definida. No sé que motivo tienes para definir la funcíon aquí pero generalmente esto solo crea confusión a no ser que sea una funcion local  que solo se use dentro del propio condicional no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Entiendo, dado que el codigo presenta errores vere como llamar a un script, hare otra pregunta para no hacer confusiones

Comment: @FJSevilla Ya llame a la funcion def y el error que me da es 

 ** File "Web_T.py", line 20, in html**
  **html(1)**
**RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded** 

No se si abrir otro hilo o aqui mismo

Comment: @Snoop13 seguramente llamas de forma recursiva a tu función, ese error indica que has superado el límite por defecto que tiene CPython de llamadas recursivas (creo que eran 1000). Es un límite por seguridad al no existir optimización de recursión por cola, es algo conservador y se puede aumentar usando  `sys.setrecursionlimit()` pero eso puede ser peligroso, en estos casos siempre mejor optimizar el código o usar iteración en lugar de recursividad. Si sigues con problemas mejor que crees una nueva pregunta y añadas tu código.

Comment: Mmm okay, @FJSevilla